# Resolving Selenium Driver issue on AWS EC2 Linux RedHat

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver

I have a peculiar issue while trying to set up Selenium WebDriver on an AWS EC2 instance running Red Hat. I'm using Google Chrome version 120.0.6099.109 on this instance.

I have been trying to install the appropriate ChromeDriver for this Chrome version, but I've encountered an intermittent problem. My Selenium Python script sometimes runs successfully, and other times, it reports that "chrome has crashed." I have tried multiple versions of ChromeDriver without consistent success.

Here's the version of Google Chrome I have:

```
$ google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 120.0.6099.109
```

I've attempted to download the corresponding ChromeDriver version (e.g., 120.0.6099.71), but the issue persists. I've also tried various versions of ChromeDriver with no consistent results.

Below is a snippet of the Python script using Selenium:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = { 
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True,
    "download.open_pdf_in_system_reader": False,
    "profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
    "download.default_directory": file_path_descargas_guias
}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)


chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

The weird thing is that sometimes IT DOES work, but most of the time it does not the cell on Jupyter Labs keeps "running" until I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SessionNotCreatedException                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 16
     13 chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
     14 chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
---> 16 driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py:45, in WebDriver.__init__(self, options, service, keep_alive)
     42 service = service if service else Service()
     43 options = options if options else Options()
---> 45 super().__init__(
     46     browser_name=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME["browserName"],
     47     vendor_prefix="goog",
     48     options=options,
     49     service=service,
     50     keep_alive=keep_alive,
     51 )

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py:61, in ChromiumDriver.__init__(self, browser_name, vendor_prefix, options, service, keep_alive)
     52 executor = ChromiumRemoteConnection(
     53     remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url,
     54     browser_name=browser_name,
   (...)
     57     ignore_proxy=options._ignore_local_proxy,
     58 )
     60 try:
---> 61     super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
     62 except Exception:
     63     self.quit()

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:209, in WebDriver.__init__(self, command_executor, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
    207 self._authenticator_id = None
    208 self.start_client()
--> 209 self.start_session(capabilities)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:293, in WebDriver.start_session(self, capabilities)
    286 """Creates a new session with the desired capabilities.
    287 
    288 :Args:
    289  - capabilities - a capabilities dict to start the session with.
    290 """
    292 caps = _create_caps(capabilities)
--> 293 response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
    294 self.session_id = response.get("sessionId")
    295 self.caps = response.get("capabilities")

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py:348, in WebDriver.execute(self, driver_command, params)
    346 response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    347 if response:
--> 348     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    349     response["value"] = self._unwrap_value(response.get("value", None))
    350     return response

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:229, in ErrorHandler.check_response(self, response)
    227         alert_text = value["alert"].get("text")
    228     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 229 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
Stacktrace:
#0 0x5635242acd33 <unknown>
#1 0x563523f69f87 <unknown>
#2 0x563523fa5e21 <unknown>
#3 0x563523fa1d9f <unknown>
#4 0x563523f9e4de <unknown>
#5 0x563523feea90 <unknown>
#6 0x563523fe30e3 <unknown>
#7 0x563523fab044 <unknown>
#8 0x563523fac44e <unknown>
#9 0x563524271861 <unknown>
#10 0x563524275785 <unknown>
#11 0x56352425f285 <unknown>
#12 0x56352427641f <unknown>
#13 0x56352424320f <unknown>
#14 0x56352429a028 <unknown>
#15 0x56352429a1f7 <unknown>
#16 0x5635242abed4 <unknown>
#17 0x7f84fd69f802 start_thread
```

or:

I did download an dunzip the webdriver and put in PATH but I'm lost right now.

I am seeking any insights into the following:

The recommended version of ChromeDriver for Google Chrome 120.0.6099.109 on Linux/Red Hat. Any specific configurations or adjustments needed for running Selenium WebDriver in headless mode on an AWS EC2 instance without display hardware. Or what would be the proper way to set  the path of the WebDriver?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t)

Comment: No it didn't, I have already followed the recommendations there and it hasn't worked out for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `selenium`, you can try `playwright`. Playwright is a newer python module, that does **not** require a webdriver.

You can install it using: `pip install playwright`

Then install the included browsers: `playwright install` and it will start downloading Chromium, Webkit, and Firefox, which come built in with `playwright`. Of course, you can also use Chrome and Microsoft Edge (running through a channel).

For example:

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(channel="chrome") #using chrome
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto('https://example.com')
    print(page.title)
    page.click('button#something') #Clicks on a button (CSS for example)
    page.close()
    browser.close()
```

and that should work. Note that in the line: `browser = p.chromium.launch(channel="chrome")`, you're not actually launching chromium, you are launching chrome. I assume the reason chromium is there before launching the correct browser is because chromium, chrome, and msedge are similar browsers. You can also do the same with firefox and webkit, just replace chromium with the desired browser, but only put the `channel` argument if you are running chrome or msedge.

Note that `playwright` launches a browser in headless mode by default (the window opens without the user seeing so), similar to certain functions of `selenium`. To change headless mode to False, add an argument called headless when launching the browser.

The reason I suggest `playwright` instead of `selenium` is that `selenium` is pretty old, and not the best choice for browser automation. `Playwright` is a newer and better version of `selenium`, and it will probably help you with your crashing problem.

Playwright: https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro